Clerk Issue: userId: null ONLY in production
I hope this message finds you well.
I'm currently facing an issue with my dashboard on Clerk and despite reaching out to their support team over the past month, I haven't been able to find a resolution. Specifically, I'm encountering an issue where, upon logging in with Clerk through Google, attempting to create a store name results in "userId: null" being returned.
Interestingly, this problem is isolated to our production environment; when testing locally on localhost:3000, everything functions as expected, and the userId is successfully retrieved.
To provide some context, I've included a link to the repository of my web application: https://github.com/ImNotKilian/incremental
Below is an excerpt from my .env file, including all relevant Clerk configurations:
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=
CLERK_SECRET_KEY=
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_URL=/sign-in
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_UP_URL=/sign-up
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_IN_URL=/
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_UP_URL=/
DATABASE_URL=''
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME=""
STRIPE_API_KEY=
FRONTEND_STORE_URL=
STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET=
I've ensured that all production secret and publishable keys for Clerk are correctly added. Additionally, my DNS settings are active.
Could anyone provide insights into why I might be encountering the "userId: null" issue exclusively in our production environment?
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
(P.S.): The ClerkProvider can be found in: app/layout.tsx. Other significant Clerk-related routes include: app/api/stores/route.ts and app/(dashboard)/[storeId]/layout.tsx.
I've exhausted several troubleshooting steps, including re-installing the DNS and adjusting the code in middleware.ts by setting publicRoutes: ["/"].
Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Could anyone provide insights into why I might be encountering the "userId: null" issue exclusively in our production environment?
